# CSS display with 3 fluid columns

Tags: html, css

I'd like to display an image in the center of the screen with some nowrap text right-aligned against the image on its left side, and some other nowrap text left-aligned against the image's right side.  As the browser window is resized horizontally, I'd like the image to shrink once there is no margin left for the nowrap'ped text.  Can this be done without using a table?

Comment: Can you add a rapid image (made in paint at least) with the graphic explanation of what you want?

Comment: Here it is with a table: http://jsfiddle.net/vvg2scqg/3/  Can it be done without a table?

Comment: Updated fiddle, is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/vvg2scqg/4/

Comment: @mrpinkman That's good but I don't want to restrict the image to 33% of the page width.  I'd rather have more image than extra white space around the text.  My table layout accomplishes this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to make a media query with the max-width set to how small the browser has to be in pixels when it starts rectifying column size

within the brackets of the media query you would style it just like you would any other css element

you would do this in your css template like so:

...

@media (max-width: 500px) {

(div class that refers to each column) {...
...
}

you can do multiple media queries for multiple smaller pixel widths

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing.  Please see my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vvg2scqg/3/